# opennms loginless readonly access

Tags: opennms

I would like to let users view opennms data without logging in. That is, the whole ui in read only mode.

I realise that I can create a guest user for this, but people then need too know the username and password for this user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked your question on the [OpenNMS-discuss](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/opennms-discuss) mailing list ([archive](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=1253674176.4754.13.camel@localhost.localdomain&forum_name=opennms-discuss)), and got the following reply:

> Assuming you are using jetty, you can modify
>   `$OPENNMS_HOME/jetty-webapps/opennms/WEB-INF/applicationContext-acegi-security.xml` and add `ROLE_ANONYMOUS` to the pages you would like to be visible without logging in. Probably OK in a friendly environment, but perhaps not if you are highly concerned about security issues. (If you're not using jetty, its `webapps` instead of `jetty-webapps` in the path)
>
> See also http://www.opennms.org/wiki/Dashboard#Anonymous_dashboards
>
> --Bill--

Comment: Thanks Bill. The installation of OpenNms we have in use now is for monitoring development and test equipment, and so we would like pretty much everyone to be able to use it if need be. Hence we arn't concenred with security with what we monitor.